# Apache Jmeter CSV Data Set Config Element only read the first line of the csv

Tags: apache, jmeter

I have a CSV file and I want to add the values to a variables. I write the variables in the "Variable Name" separated with commas, like: "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h",
In the CSV file I have 5 words in the first line and in the Debug Sampler I get the following.
a=word one, b=word two, c= word three, d= word four, e=word five,
and I have no f,g,h variables.
How could It go to the next line?
Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please increase the Number of Threads(users) count to 2 to go in next line, This field can be found in thread group settings.
i.e 
[image]

Increasing the thread count will execute again and in second run it will pick next line

Comment: Yes, this was the solution, I solved this after 5 hours thinking :D But thank you. :)

Comment: @Chris
 please mark this as a correct solution then